# Layout of app not to right size on moblie phone

Tags: android

I have been working on a app for sometime now. I have only been working and looking on my emulator and never put it on a android phone to see results along the way. But now I have, and i'v seen what it looks like. Some buttons are high and low here there,my text is all out of sink.So what I would like to know is how can I make my app fit to the size of the screen on most android phones.Because on the emulator it looks fine.

```
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10"  

    Android Version 2.3.6
    kernel version 2.6.35.7-1187001
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use relativeLayouts, and relative positionings

Comment: I am useing relative Layouts at the moment..not sure what relative positionings is tho

Answer (score 0):

How are you mentioning button sizes?
You will have to use dp and sp size rather than mentioning actual button sizes.

Comment: I am using dp at the moment